# Inner join using Case statement , searching for better options

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamic, runtime, case, inner-join

i have tried to use CASE statement to change join condition depending on input values in sql server, i have write example to explain for this as below

```
go
declare @parentNumber int=0
declare @parent table (prowid bigint,name varchar(200));
insert into @parent (prowid,name) values (1,'A');
insert into @parent (prowid,name) values (2,'B');

declare @child table(crowid bigint,prowid bigint,prowid2 bigint, name varchar(200));
insert into @child (crowid,prowid,prowid2,name) values (1,1,2,'AA_BA')
insert into @child (crowid,prowid,prowid2,name) values (2,1,2,'AB_BB')
insert into @child (crowid,prowid,prowid2,name) values (3,1,2,'AC_BC')

--parentname will be of prowid
select pr.name as ParentName,ch.* from @parent pr
inner join @child ch on 
(CASE WHEN @parentNumber=0 THEN ch.prowid ELSE ch.prowid2 END)=pr.prowid

SET @parentNumber=1
--parentname will be of prowid2
select pr.name as ParentName,ch.* from @parent pr
inner join @child ch on 
(CASE WHEN @parentNumber=0 THEN ch.prowid ELSE ch.prowid2 END)=pr.prowid

go
```

i have table parameter so you can run directly in your query window, as far as i know case statements slower the query execution. so i am here if anyone can suggest me better solution... except of using another join... like

```
select * from @child ch
inner join @parent p on p.prowid=ch.prowid
inner join @parent p2 on p.prowid=ch.prowid2
```

waiting for everyone's reply........

Comment: Are you just swicthing on @parentNumber only?

Comment: is there any other way to do this , changing the join with input params..

Comment: by switching @parentNumber entire join query changes

Answer (score 3):

Don't be clever, just have different SELECTs

```
IF @parentNumber=0
    select pr.name as ParentName,ch.* from @parent pr
    inner join @child ch on  ch.prowid = pr.prowid
ELSE
    select pr.name as ParentName,ch.* from @parent pr
    inner join @child ch on ch.prowid2 = pr.prowid
```

Comment: this is just sample example, real queries are far bigger

Comment: @SamirTank: in which case, this is the best way to get efficient plans for each case. A "general" plan will run like shit

Comment: i know , that's the point, i want to know if any better solution can be used to achieve this..

Comment: @SamirTank: I just gave you *the* most efficient solution: dedicated SELECTs for each case...

Comment: using selects for each case will increase maintain cost, i would use isnull(nullif(.. if it was condition,but i want to find same for inner-join's

Comment: @SamirTank: Stay with your case and take the performance hit then. Your choice